# High memory allocation when using dask.bag.map

Tags: python, memory-management, dask

I am using dask for extending dask bag items by information from an external, previously computed object `arg`. Dask seems to allocate memory for `arg` for each partition at once in the beginning of the computation process.

Is there a workaround to prevent Dask from duplicating the `arg` multiple times (and allocating a lot of memory)?

Here is a simplified example:

```
from pathlib import Path

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from dask import bag

in_dir = Path.home() / 'in_dir'
out_dir = Path.home() / 'out_dir'

in_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
out_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

n_files = 100
n_lines_per_file = int(1e6)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': np.arange(n_lines_per_file).astype(str)
})

for i in range(n_files):
    df.to_csv(in_dir / f'{i}.txt', index=False, header=False)


def mapper(x, arg):
    y = x  # map x to y using arg
    return y


arg = np.zeros(int(1e7))

(
    bag
    .read_text(str(in_dir / '*.txt'))
    .map((lambda x, y: x), arg)
    .to_textfiles(str(out_dir / '*.txt'))
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One strategy for dealing with this is to [`scatter`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/futures.html#distributed.Client.scatter) your data to workers first:

```py
import dask.bag, dask.distributed

client = dask.distributed.Client()

arg = np.zeros(int(1e7))
arg_f = client.scatter(arg, broadcast=True)

(
    dask.bag
    .read_text(str(in_dir / '*.txt'))
    .map((lambda x, y: x), arg_f)
    .to_textfiles(str(out_dir / '*.txt'))
)
```

This sends a copy of the data to each worker, but does not create a copy for each task.